# No Sound - sound cards are not visible on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I am having this problem since last 10 days, first it was showing dummy output, I tried all the possible solutions suggested online but nothing worked. I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday with the hope that this issue will get solved but nothing seems to work.

When I run the command pulseaudio in terminal I get this message

```
E: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: 

org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```

Please help me. Thank you.

[image: Screenshot the output of alsamixer and sound setting of my system]

Comment: Did you do anything special 10 days ago? Do you have sound in your guest account?

Comment: Surprisingly, the audio is working fine but still, there is no audio card visible and even the volume of my device shows mute. Strange! however, the headset is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

To help your troubleshooting ... I have that error as well on a functioning:

Ubuntu 18.04 (3)
Kernel 5.0.0-34-generic
Nvidia 440.XX "Open Source"

and it is not affecting the Laptop seemingly adversely.

I was curious about this error as well!  It says it is "Important", but again, the system is working fine.